# Can you transfer a Bluetooth socket from one activity to another in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-bluetooth

I am building a BTchat application project in android studio,
The first activity sets up the connection and after the devices are connected we move to the next activity. I have used an application class with methods like getBTSocket() and setBTSocket(). In the second activity when there is the call of getBTSocket() my app closes/crashes(whatever you may call it).

Here is the code for socket.

```
public void setBluetoothSocket ( BluetoothSocket socket1 ) {
    socket = socket1;
}

public BluetoothSocket getBTSocket()  {
    return socket;
}
```

Please tell me what should I do.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it without static field (bad way).

`BluetoothSocket` is not serializable and is not parcelable to send it through the `Intent`.

You need to open/close connection inside activity, and for navigation use only fragments. When activity calls `onStop()` - close connection, restart it `onResume()`

Another way is Android Service: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service

Comment: how should I proceed with Service, I mean there is a serverThread(for listening) and a clientThread(for connecting to selected device) which I used in my code. How should I use service